# Adding SecKeyRef, SecIdentityRefs to an OS X Keychain

Tags: security, macos, keychain

There exists the handy `SecCertificateAddToKeychain()` function, which allows a developer to add "floating" certificates (e.g. `SecCertificateRef` instances generated by `SecCertificateCreateWithData()`) to a keychain.

Where are the equivalent functions for `SecKeyRef` and `SecIdentityRef` instances? There is `SecKeychainItemImport()`, but it's for importing raw data. There is also `SecItemAdd()`, but it's limited to adding passwords.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

`SecItemAdd` is quite capable of adding certificates and keys to a keychain; just set the `kSecClass` attribute to the item's class (e.g. kSecClassKey) and pass the item references in an array in the `kSecUseItemList` attribute.

The only caveat is that a single call to `SecItemAdd` can only add items of the same class; if you want to add a certificate and a key, you need to do it in two calls.

You don't need to explicitly create or add identities to a keychain; they are implicit constructs that are automatically created when both the certificate and its private key are available.